# On p-Sylow subgroups of locally finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I've come across this problem (I'm sorry if it's poorly written but it's a translation); for a $p$-Sylow I mean a $p$-subgroup that is not contained in any other $p$-subgroup: 
Let $G$ be a locally finite group with a finite $p$-Sylow. Show that all the $p$-Sylow of $G$ are finite and conjugate. 

Now, the problem above this one, whose demonstration nearly drove me crazy, states that if $G$, not necessarily finite, has a finite number of conjugate for a $p$-Sylow, than all the $p$-Sylow are conjugate. Thus if in the problem I proposed I manage to show that there is a $p$-Sylow with a finite orbit under conjugation, I'm done. 
The problem is that I should prove it using elementary tools (the only thing I managed to find relevant is a post on MO concerning higher level results); that said, this is the only thing I could come up with: 

Let $S_0$ be the set of all the "linearly independent" (in the sense that no element can be expressed only using the other ones) elements of $G$ whose order is a power of $p$. Now let $S$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by all the $s_i$'s of $S_0$. Now if let's say $s_1$ and $s_2$ generate a $p$-Sylow, then there can't be no $s_j$ in $S_0$ so that $\langle s_1,s_2,s_i \rangle$ is a p-group as that would mean that $\langle s_1,s_2 \rangle$ is not maximal. 
Another idea was to work with conjugation on either $S$ or $S_0$, but as they're infinite I don't know how to procede


The fact is that I could show that the result is true in $S$, but I'm not sure that's true (I'm quite sure it's false), or I could work in some way in $S$ and then jumping back on $G$

Comment: If I understand right, a $p$-Sylow in this context (i.e. before you've proven the theorem) is defined to mean a $p$-subgroup that is not properly contained in another $p$-subgroup. Let me know if this is wrong.

Comment: Yes, maybe I need to specify it; ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Proposition** Let  be a locally finite group with a finite Sylow $p$-subgroup. Then all the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ are finite and conjugate.

**Proof** Let $P$ be an arbitrary finite $p$-subgroup of $G$ and $S$ the given finite Sylow $p$-subgroup. Since $G$ is locally finite, $H=\langle P,S \rangle$ is finite. Of course, $S$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$, hence $P$ must be contained in some ($H$-)conjugate of $S$. Hence $|P| \leq |S|$ and, by definition (in the infinite case as a *maximal* $p$-subgroup), the order of any $p$-subgroup of $G$ cannot be larger than $|S|$. It follows that any Sylow $p$-subgroup must be finite. And the above reasoning shows that in fact any Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ must be conjugate to $S$.

Comment: on the other hand couldn't there be an infinite p-Sylow subgroups that does not contain S in any of its conjugates?

Comment: Your first question: this is just an application of Sylow's Theorem in the *finite* case, since $H$ is finite!

Comment: oh, yes I got it. but why can you suppose that P is finite? what about all the infinite Sylow p-subgroups

Comment: @temp suppose $Q\leqslant G$ is an infinite p-subgroup. let $X\subseteq Q$ be any finite subset with $|X|>S$. then $\langle X\rangle$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$ of size $>S$, and it is finite since $G$ is locally finite, contradicting the finite case

Comment: ty ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Atticus Stonestrom, thanks for filling in, I was too busy preparing X-mas here at home. We will be enjoying the wine $\Phi$, Fibonacci, yes it really exists, from Sicilia. Merry X-Mas to you all!